# How to join an idle/achievement server?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

How do I join an Idle/Achievement Server in CS:GO?

Comment: @Studoku While I don't like this question either, I really don't think we should be closing it without actually having a proper reason for doing so.  We're not really doing ourselves any favors by capriciously closing questions.  It degrades the new user experience something fierce.

Comment: @Frank Sorry. Was going to close it as a recommendation but must have clicked the wrong thing.

Comment: You find one, and then you join it. Which part is causing you trouble?

Comment: User has not come back since asking.  I don't believe there's enough here to be able to help, so I am voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @Frank  what is unclear about it exactly? I really don't understand the down voting. Are all of you just upset he's using unethical means to get drops of pixels?

Comment: @Sickest Presumably, he knows how to connect to servers in general, as that's not what's being asked.  Since achievement servers can be joined just as easily as other servers, there seems to be something else going on here.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty Simple, Open CS:GO, Press Play, Goto Browse Community Servers Press Ok on the warning. Type Idle in the search. And connect to a server.

[image]
[image]